# Parameters and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few name elements in a html document that i want to pass to the jquery function assigned to a variable named "elements"

I want to assign the value of the clicked elements ID to the variable x.

I am new to JQuery can somebody help me please.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('color');

$(elements).click(function() {
   x = $(this).id;

});
```

Comment: Could you just add a common class to the elements you want to select?  Then just use $('.yourClassName').click(function() { ... });

Comment: `$(this).id` should be `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: @ChrisWillard yeah I could do that, but then how would I assign the elements ID which I clicked to x?

Comment: @user3453366 Do you want to assign the ID of the element you click to x?  In that case, similar to what you've already done - x = $(this).attr('id')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont want to use jquery with javascript DOM Objects you've already gotten.  You can grab the objects as Jquery objects with the class selector.

```
$('.color').click(function() {
     x = this.id;
     alert(x);
});
```

Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/2gmM3/

Comment: Passing an array of dom objects to a jQuery selector is fine. It may be unnecessary here, but it works. Also, given his code, `color` is the `name`, not the class name.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#color').click(function() {
   x = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: He's looking for elements with the `name` of `color`, not the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    var x;
    $('[name="color"]').on('click', function(){
        x = $(this).attr('id'); 
        alert(x);
    });
});
```

**[Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/Ds9kS/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('html').on('click', '[name="color"]', function(){
   var x = $(this).attr('id');
})
```